# php curl jsessionid how to save and use save session id and cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl, jsessionid

Okay so I have a phpcurl script belown that grabs the cookie and shows me a page I will post these below.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/stats.po';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

this scrip correctly saves the cookie file and I get this on the outut of curl wich matches the session id in header and saved in cookie file .

```
<p>This document you requested has moved temporarily.</p> <p>http://www.example.com/stats.po&#59;JSESSIONID_oschA=GQ4ySdFRyqjk12hj45GM4c6LG0KRj8f4pzvD3YSvrql9BwdGgNyn!-1634352464">https://www.example.com/stats.po&#59;JSESSIONID_oschA=GQ4ySdFRyqjk12hj45GM4c6LG0KRj8f4pzvD3YSvrql9BwdGgNyn!-1634352464</a>.</p>
```

how can I now goto the jsession url link given to me in the output whilst still using same cookie ect ect

Comment: Did you try making another curl request ?

Comment: that's what I am trying to ask how do I make another request with curl whilst still passing the same data I am new to all this and just need a helping hand its took me a while to get here :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think if you make the first curl request with the CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION set to 1, then remove that option in the second request you should be good.  I am not an expert on this subject, but the documentation for CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION seems to match the symptoms you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

**This should still use same cookies for both requests**

```
<?php
function mycurl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result= curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $result;
}
echo mycurl("http://www.example.com/stats.po");
echo mycurl("http://www.example.com/stats2.po");
?>
```

Comment: okay bro I can see this working just one little thing is there a way I can parse the session id given to me in the first request to the url for the second curl operation

Comment: I have just tried this out this will not work as it creates a new session id every time I make a curl reqesuest

Comment: Are you sure the cookie is saved in cookies.txt

Comment: yes 100% sure I can view it in my cpanel . every time a curl reqest is made it changes the session id I need to be able to pass the cookie and keep the same session id

Comment: I think I can fix this with a little work any chance u can help me with one thing how can I extract the jsessionid from the php header